# Finding Minimum element in a tree

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am trying to find Maximum and Minimum element in a binary tree. This is my function to find the maximum and minimum element in a binary tree.

Minimum Function:-

```
int findMin(struct Node* root) 
{ 
    queue<Node *> q;
    q.push(root);
    int min=INT_MAX;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        root=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(root->data<min)
        {
            min=root->data;
        }
        if(root->left)
        {
            q.push(root->left);
        }
        if(root->right)
        {
            q.push(root->right);
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Maximum function:-

```
int findMax(Node* root) 
{ 
    queue<Node *> q;
    q.push(root);
    int max=0;
    while(!q.empty())
    {
        root=q.front();
        q.pop();
        if(root->data>max)
        {
            max=root->data;
        }
        if(root->left)
        {
            q.push(root->left);
        }
        if(root->right)
        {
            q.push(root->right);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

But According to GeeksforGeeks when i run this function, it has exceeded time limit. But I am sure that this is correct. Please enlighten me If i am making any mistake?

Range of N:- `1<N<10^5`

Comment: It is a binary search tree, right? You do not have to recurse into both branches, just pick the correct one.

Comment: `if(root->data<min)` is unreadable.

Comment: please include a [mcve]. GeeksforGeeks now also offers competitions? Great!

Comment: time limit exceeded does not mean that your code is wrong, it just takes too long

Comment: Hint: BST -> O(logN), general tree -> O(N).

Comment: @Evg It is working fine on my compiler

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 that's why I have Included the range.

Comment: what is `N`? The number of nodes in the tree? Please include a [mcve]. Also it is not quite clear what the question is. Your code must not be wrong to trigger a "time limit exceeded"

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 okay

Comment: It is readable for a compiler, but not for a human being. Cf.: `if (root->data < min)`.

Comment: @Evg Thanks Buddy, I will improve it.

Comment: The code looks correct for a general tree. Time limit exceeded probably means you are supposed to do something a bit smarter, but without seeing the full context it's hard to know what that might be. Can you provide a link to the original problem?